# how to run vaadin charts demo in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, vaadin7, vaadin-charts

Tried following these instructions https://github.com/vaadin/charts/blob/7a55e8dab5b9941a05603c2624a576866e86045d/DevInstructions.md, but I can't do the download dependencies step, even though it worked yesterday. Widget compile also does not work.

In 'vaadin-charts-directorypackage' it shows 4 errors after import

```
Failed to run task (com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:0.0.23:bower:bower install:generate-resources)

Failed to run task (com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:0.0.23:gulp:gulp deploy:deploy)

Failed to run task (com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:0.0.23:gulp:gulp stage:generate-resources)

Failed to run task (com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:0.0.23:npm:npm install:generate-resources)

Caused by: com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.lib.TaskRunnerException: 'npm install --color=false' failed. (error code 34)
```

Then after Add Facets:

```
Cannot change version of project facet Dynamic Web Module to 2.4.   vaadin-charts-demo      line 1  Maven Java EE Configuration Problem

Java compiler level does not match the version of the installed Java project facet. vaadin-charts-demo      Unknown Faceted Project Problem (Java Version Mismatch)

One or more constraints have not been satisfied.    vaadin-charts-demo      line 1  Maven Java EE Configuration Problem
```

How do I fix these errors? Simply want to be able to run the charts demo, doesn't seem like it should be difficult, but can't get past these errors.  Tried googling errors one by one, but not sure how to apply changes to the different files/projects that are imported/related to 'vaadin-charts-demo'

Answer (score 1):

Looks like DevInstructions.md has been outdated for a while, thanks for noticing, I'll create a ticket for that.

About running the demos, if you're using only maven you need to run install in parent project, and then jetty:run in demo project.

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/vaadin/charts.git
cd charts/
mvn clean install -DskipTests
cd demo/
mvn jetty:run
```

Note that install might fail for some modules if you don't do the recursive clone because submodule will be missing, but the relevant modules will be built and jetty:run should work for demo.

If you are using Eclipse and have workspace resolution importing demo, examples and addon modules should be enough to be able to use jetty:run in the demo.